# How to dynamically change superview's height with autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have two subviews in a view, and their sizes are managed with constraints in auto layout.

How can I change the height of superview, in relation to the height of the subviews?

I just created a repository that has the problem : https://github.com/Deviasoft-Official/IOS-ScrollViewAndAutoLayout

More precisely, my question is how to delete the line 36 in this file:
https://github.com/Deviasoft-Official/IOS-ScrollViewAndAutoLayout/blob/master/ScrollViewAndAutolayout/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

This question is discussed here.

[Resize the superview automatically with auto layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444389/can-subviews-resize-their-superview-automatically-with-auto-layout).

[UIScrollView auto height in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870721/uiscrollview-auto-height-in-swift/34871051#34871051)

I managed to attain this by applying auto layouts in xib. Try the same logic in Visual Format, if you are not using xib.
Otherwise, if xib is there, better to give constraints there.