# Detect a UIScrollView's height dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a real problem with detecting UIScrollView height. I searched a lot and found this solution:

[image]

So I dragged from `Content View` to `View` and made `Equal Height`. But I does not work for me.

I also tried to calculate scrollView height according to elements height in it, but I do not think that it's a right way.

How can I set UIScrollView height dynamically? What is the correct way for doing it?

Comment: What do you want to add in scrollview ? Do you want to display some text inside that ?

Comment: @BharathVankireddy there are many UITables, UIViews, UILabels, etc.

Comment: Have you considered to place all your elements directly inside the scrollView? Is there a good reason to have a content view?

Answer (score 1):

Your `ScrollView` should add a **ContentView** like this:

[image]

select your `scrollView` and in size Inspector bottom, set the width like this:

[image: my inspector setting]

for more details on how to handle `scrollView` in **Interface Builder** your can check out this AppleDoc [Working with Scroll Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH24-SW1)

Hope this help you!

Comment: and it will change the height automatically? I did it, but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You only way to set height of your `scrollView` is by calculating the height of individual objects added to scrollview.

Programatically, calculate the height of each UI object and at the end set content height to scrollview.

```
[scView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, height)];
```

In above line, 'height' is nothing but a sum of all heights of all UI objects calculated.

Answer (score 0):

By doing the below stuff's, I was able to implement UIScrollView with Automatic height based on the contents inside.

1. Add scrollview to the main view.
2. Add one ContentView inside this container scroll view.
3. Give proper constraints inside this content
   view to the container scroll view as well as to its internal UI
   Components. Please note that you should not give fixed height to the
   content View. The constraints of the content view should grow
   according to the UI Components inside
4. This might give you a layout
   warning as 'Unambigous.... '. To fix this, give 'Equal Heights' constraint relation between content view and scroll view

Try the above steps, and this will solve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add item (UIView, UILabel...) in your UIScrollView by auto layout? If so, just put these in it and create correct constraints for them.

The key point is each item which in UIScrollView have top, leading, bottom and trailing side constraints to their **superview**. Most important is **Make Sure** that your UIScrollView has top, leading, bottom and trailing Descendant Constraints to its sub-items. It will calculate correct content height of scroll view for you.

In your solution, if your contentView has zero frame, it will not give you any height for scroll view.